# Jupyter notebook not working with Pycharm

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, jupyter

I am trying to use jupyter notebook on Pycharm.
Following [this article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2019/07/jupyter-pycharm-and-pizza/), I ran a simple Hello World code but nothing shows up.
I got some logs like this.

```
/home/ryuzot/anaconda3/envs/keras_playground2/bin/jupyter notebook --no-browser --port 8888
[I 00:52:46.955 NotebookApp]  Serving notebooks from local directory:
/home/ryuzot/PycharmProjects/keras_playground
[I 00:52:46.955 NotebookApp] Jupyter Notebook 6.1.1 is running at:
[I 00:52:46.955 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/? 
token=45771778a508593eb6b45db8b13b2661daea7a4b709846d6
[I 00:52:46.955 NotebookApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/? 
token=45771778a508593eb6b45db8b13b2661daea7a4b709846d6
[I 00:52:46.955 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 00:52:46.957 NotebookApp] 

    To access the notebook, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/ryuzot/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-13870-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=45771778a508593eb6b45db8b13b2661daea7a4b709846d6
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/?token=45771778a508593eb6b45db8b13b2661daea7a4b709846d6
```

I change the port which jupyter is running to 8888 and 8080, but it didn't work.
I use Pycharm professional 2020.2, Jupyter Notebook 6.1.1 , Python 3.7 on openSUSE 15.2.
I hope to receive some help.

Answer (score -1):

To start working with Jupyter notebooks in PyCharm:
Create a new Python project, specify a virtual environment, and install the jupyter package.

Open or create a `.ipynb` file.

Add and edit source cells.

Execute any of the code cells to launch the Jupyter server.

Analyze execution results in the Preview pane.